# Computing ${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}t}\left(e^{it}\right)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Is the following elementary calculation correct?

$$
{\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}t}\left(e^{it}\right) = \underbrace{{\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}t}\left(it\right) \cdot {\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}z}\left(e^{it}\right)}_{\text{via the chain rule}} = i e^{{it}}
$$

Comment: yes, 100% correct!

Comment: Since $i$ is rotation by $90^\circ$, we can see that the velocity is at a right angle to position and, if you were to differentiate again, acceleration would be opposite to position. Since $e^{it}$ is a circle on the complex plane, this should ring a bell (if you've taken physics)!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

We could do this another way, too.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}e^{it}&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\cos{t}+i\sin{t}\right)\\
&=-\sin{t}+i\cos{t}\\
&=i\left(\cos{t}+i\sin{t}\right)\\
&=ie^{it}
\end{align}$$
Be careful, because you technically need a more rigorous definition of complex exponentials and derivatives for complex numbers.  However, it is consistent with this rule of elementary calculus.